Reference for Hurewicz's theorem in algebraic topology
Let me begin by stating that under no circumstances am I an expert in algebraic topology. That being said, some years ago I came across Hurewicz's theorem relating the (co)homology groups to the fundemental groups of a topological space $X$. I know were to find references for that simpler statement.
If I am not mistaken though, and correct me if I am, the theorem can be stated in a general fashion as $$H^{n}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(  \frac{\pi_{n}(X)}{\left[\pi_{n}(X),\pi_{n}(X) \right]}, \mathbb{Z}\right).$$ Can someone give a reference for the proof of the above?
Can the theorem be generalized even more?

The Hom should be from $\pi_n(X)$ to $\mathbb Z$

You also need to specify $n$. The Hurewicz theorem holds up to and including the first degree in which $\pi_n(X) \neq 0$ (if any), but not for higher degrees.

There's a number of mistakes in the version in you statement of the theorem. A correct (and somewhat more general) statement would be something like this:

Theorem 1: (Hurewicz) Let $X$ be an $n$-connected space (i.e. $\pi_k X = 0$ for all $k \leq n$), $n \geq 0$, and let $G$ be any abelian group. Then there is an isomorphism
$$
    H^{n + 1}(X; G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}((\pi_{n + 1} X)^\mathrm{ab}, G)
$$
of abelian groups.

Here $(\pi_n X)^\mathrm{ab} := \pi_n X / [\pi_n X, \pi_n X]$ is the abelianization of $\pi_n X$. I don't know a reference for this exact form of the theorem, but it's not difficult to put it together yourself.
To do that, we will rely on a more usual form of the Hurewicz theorem; this often comes in two parts, one for the fundamental group and one for higher homotopy groups. Both of the following statements are based on those in A. Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology," specifically Theorems 2A.1 and 4.32. Proofs can also be found there.

Theorem 2: (Hurewicz) Let $X$ be a 0-connected (i.e. path-connected) space. Then there is a surjective group homomorphism $h\colon \pi_1(X) \to H_1(X)$ whose kernel is $[\pi_1 X, \pi_1 X]$, whence it induces an isomorphism $(\pi_1 X)^\mathrm{ab} \cong H_1(X)$.


Theorem 3: (Hurewicz) Let $X$ be an $n$-connected space. Then $\tilde{H}_i(X) = 0$ for all $i \leq n$ and $\pi_{n + 1} X \cong H_{n + 1}(X)$.

The only other ingredient we need is the following:

Proposition 4: If $X$ is $n$-connected for some $n \geq 0$ and $G$ is any abelian group, then $H^{n + 1}(X; G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_{n + 1}(X), G)$.

Proof: The universal coefficient theorem tells us that
$$
    H^{n + 1}(X; G) \cong \operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(H_n(X), G) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(H_{n + 1}(X), G)
$$
for all spaces $X$ and all $n$. Plugging in our hypotheses, we now distinguish two cases: Either $n = 0$, in which case $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(H_n(X), G)$ vanishes by virtue of $H_0(X)$ being free, or $n > 0$ in which case it vanishes since $H_n(X) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X) = 0$ by virtue of Theorem 3. In either case we obtain $H^{n + 1}(X; G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_{n + 1}(X), G)$ as desired. $\Box$
From this it's not hard to obtain Theorem 1: In its setting, if $n = 0$, then $H_1(X) \cong (\pi_1 X)^\mathrm{ab}$ by virtue of Theorem 2, and if $n > 0$ then $H_{n + 1}(X) \cong \pi_{n + 1} X$ by virtue of Theorem 3, but this group is already abelian, i.e. $\pi_{n + 1} X \cong (\pi_{n + 1} X)^\mathrm{ab}$, so combining this and plugging it into Proposition 4 gives exactly what we wanted.

I don't think this can be generalized much further; in fact, Theorem 1 doesn't really deserve to be called a generalization of Theorems 2 and 3 in my opinion. It's simply a corollary that can be obtained using bog standard techniques.
The only thing left to address is the question of naturality, and the answer is what one would hope it is: The isomorphism in Theorem 1 is natural both in $X$ and in $G$ (where we consider $X$ as an object of the full subcategory of $\mathrm{Top}$ spanned by the $n$-connected spaces). This follows more or less directly from the naturality properties of the universal coefficient theorem and the Hurewicz maps in Theorems 2 and 3.

If you want a generalization, Kan's 1958 paper A Combinatorial Definition of Homotopy Groups addresses in Chapter III "in what precise sense the homology groups are 'abelianized homotopy groups' " — no connectivity restrictions.
